# Check if a REBOL string contains another string

Tags: rebol

I tried using the `find` function to check for the occurrence of the string `"ll"` in the string `"hello"`, but it returns `"ll"` instead of `true` or `false`:

```
"This prints 'll'"
print find "hello" "ll"
```

Does REBOL's standard library have any functions to check if a string contains another string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
>> print found? find "hello" "ll"
true
>> print found? find "hello" "abc"
false
```

Comment: Also, there is a function to count the number of occurrences of one string in another string: http://rebol-land.blogspot.com/2013/12/count-string-occurrence-in-string.html

Answer (score 1):

@ShixinZeng is correct that there is a FOUND? in Rebol.  However, it is simply defined as:

```
found?: function [
    "Returns TRUE if value is not NONE."
    value
] [
    not none? :value
]
```

As it is equivalent to `not none?`...you could have written:

```
>> print not none? find "hello" "ll"
true
>> print not none? find "hello" "abc"
false
```

Or if you want the other bias:

```
>> print none? find "hello" "ll"
false
>> print none? find "hello" "abc"
true
```

Intended to help with readability while using FIND.  However, I don't like it because it has confusing behavior by working when not used with FIND, e.g.

```
>> if found? 1 + 2 [print "Well this is odd..."]
Well this is odd...
```

Since you can just use the result of the FIND in a conditional expression with IF and UNLESS and EITHER, you don't really need it very often...unless you are assigning the result to a variable you really want to be boolean.  In which case, I don't mind using NOT NONE? or NONE? as appropriate.

And in my opinion, losing FOUND? from the core would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

as written in prior answers **find** gives you back already a result you can use in conditional expressions.

```
>> either find "hello" "ll" [
[    print "hit"
[    ] [
[    print "no hit"
[    ]
hit
```

or in a more rebolish way

```
>> print either find "hello" "ll" [ "hit"] [ "no hit"]
hit
```

But you can also use **to-logic** on the result giving you **true** or **false**

```
>> print to-logic find "hello" "ll"
true
>> print  find "hello" "lzl"                 
none
>> print  to-logic find "hello" "lzl"
false
```